# Nginx rewrite to proxy_pass server/path

Tags: nginx, nginx-location

Is it possible to use Nginx proxy_pass to rewrite URL as below:

```
location /foo {
    proxy_pass http://external-server-IP:8080/some/path/;
}
```

Comment: If you want a *rewrite*, this is not the way to go. Using `proxy_pass` passes the request (usually) to a gateway interface (CGI, WSGI, etc.). See the [docs](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_rewrite_module.html#rewrite).

Comment: See [the `proxy_pass` documentation](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_pass), but source and target URI should both end with `/`, or neither end with `/`. Otherwise use a `rewrite ... break`.

Answer (score 1):

Just in case someone still needs this, the easy way to do this:

```
    location ~ ^/foo/.* {
        rewrite ^/foo(.*) /$1 break;
        proxy_pass https://external-server:8080/remote-path/;
    }

    rewrite ^/foo$ /foo/ redirect;
```

What this does is that it sends the request to the external server, masquerading it under your own domain.

`rewrite ^/foo(.*) /$1 break;`
The first rewrite is just to remove the added URL path (the remote server is not expecting that.

`rewrite ^/foo$ /foo/ redirect;`
And the 2nd rewrite is just in case you want to use the index page, so that it actually goes to the remote index page as well.